# On the extension of a limit

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

We know that $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\left\Vert \left(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)\right\Vert _{p}=\max\left\{ \left|x_{1}\right|,\cdots,\left|x_{n}\right|\right\} =:\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{\infty}$
for any $\left(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)\in R^{n}$. Now
do we have $\lim_{p\rightarrow0}\left\Vert \left(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)\right\Vert _{p}=\left\Vert \left(x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}\right)\right\Vert _{0}:=\mbox{cardinality}\left\{ x_{i}:x_{i}\neq0\right\} $?

Comment: I have fixed the LateX, but the question as it stands is still nonsensical, because when $0<p<1$ it is really quite hard to take a limit as $p\to\infty$ ...

Comment: Thanks Yemon, I was mistaken about it ending mid sentence (I just couldn't see parts of the second sentence) and I deleted that comment.  I knew there was something fishy when I read "if p>1".

Comment: I tried to make the question a little more sensible.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by $\|\cdot\|_p$ when $0<p<1$.  This is obviously false if $\|x\|_p=(\sum |x_k|^p)^{1/p}$ (consider $n=1$) and obviously true if $\|x\|_p=\sum |x_k|^p$.

Comment: The first bullet point at http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot lists some sites where you can find further help.

Comment: Should add that I have downvoted this question based on lack of context (is this an exercise? a curiosity? something needed to make progress? etc.) and low level of question.

Comment: In addition to Jonas' comment, there is a third interesting limit: $\lim_{p \to 0} ((1/n) \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^p)^{1/p}$ has a very pretty value.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of mentioning that.  It's an exercise in Rudin's Real and Complex analysis for general probability spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Hardy-Littlewood-Polya *Inequalities*.
Contains considerable material on these $(|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$, including for example $p=-1$ and of course limiting cases at $p=\infty$, $p=0$, $p=-\infty$.